# What is the type of visa I need to stay at a hotel outside Heathrow, London?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, layovers, lhr

I am a student from India heading to the USA.
I am transiting through London and have a very long layover (22 hours) at Heathrow.
My flight from India arrives at noon at Heathrow, and the flight to USA departs the next day at 10 AM.
I plan to spend the night at a hotel outside Heathrow or at my cousin's place.

The UK site says I need a Visitor in Transit visa if I need to leave the airport. But since I hold a valid visa to USA, I may be exempt from that too (mentioned in the same site – **"transit without visa concession"**)

Questions:

1. Is the Visitor in Transit visa only applicable for people transiting to another airport within UK or can be used for staying outside/sightseeing also?
   **The UK Visa wizard site says I can get a 'Visitor in Transit' visa for this, but the Visa4UK site says I can't use the 'Visitor in Transit' visa for any other purpose other than transiting to another airport.**
2. What are the chances of being allowed entry to London with a "transit without visa concession"?
3. Even if I get a visa, is there a chance for my entry to London getting denied?

Comment: What kind of US visa do you have? That may make a difference, as there are transit visa exemptions for people going to/from certain countries (including the USA) where they hold a visa for that country

Comment: See: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-stop-in-the-uk