# Do I need a visa to stay at a hotel close to Heathrow before connecting to a flight to Vancouver, Canada?

Tags: visas, uk, layovers, lhr

My daughter and I are travelling to Vancouver, Canada through Heathrow but staying all night to get connected. I have a valid multi-entry visa to the UK that I obtained for previous travel, but my daughter does not because her destination is Canada. Do we need a visa to spend the night at a hotel close to Heathrow? We both have Ethiopian passports.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-stop-in-the-uk

Answer (score 3):

If you stay at a hotel near the airport, then you need to exit the airport. That means that you must ensure that you can legally pass border control.

From the link for [the Gov.UK](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/ethiopia/transit/yes) website @Karlson provided,

You’ll need a visa to pass through the UK in transit

> **You should apply for a Visitor in Transit visa if you arrive on a flight and will pass
> through immigration control before you leave the UK.**
>
> **Transiting without a visa
> You might be eligible for the ‘transit without visa concession’ if:**
>
> - you arrive and depart by air
> - have a confirmed onward flight which leaves within 24 hours
> - have the right documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country)
>
> One of the following must also apply:
>
> - you’re travelling to Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and have a valid visa for that country

As you might expect the transit with visa concessions is entirely up to the Immigration official, so **if you want to be absolutely sure, get a Land side transit visa.**

> The ‘transit without visa concession’ is decided by the immigration officer at the border. You won’t be allowed to transit if they decide you need a visa, so you might want to apply for a transit visa before you travel.