# Travelling from India to canada via Dubai and London. Do I need a transit visa

Tags: visas, transit, uk, indian-citizens, dubai

I am travelling to Calgary from Delhi. I have an Air India flight from Delhi to Dubai then British Airways flight from Dubai to London and Air Canada flight from London to Calgary. My query is "Do I require a transit visa." Plz help as I am travelling in four days

Comment: Regarding London, see [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/34106/9801). You may need to specify your nationality for an answer about Dubai.

Comment: And do you require a transit visa at which location?  You have 2 transit points.

Comment: I meant, do I require at any of these 2 airports? I am an Indian citizen

Comment: Thanks Nick, I am an Indian citizen. This link talks about some exceptions i e whether u need to recheck in your baggage. How do I ascertain that ?

Answer (score 3):

*Assuming you have Indian citizenship with some sort of Canadian authorization (study, tourist, etc.). This question is irrelevant if you have British or Canadian citizenship. Also, judging by your name, I know you don't have Emirati citizenship.*

---

I think you may have a problem. Let me explain.

I have done the following routes several times:

- `DXB` → `(somewhere in Europe)` → `(somewhere in Canada)`
- `BOM` → `(somewhere in Europe)` → `(somewhere in Canada)`
- `BOM` → `DXB` → `(somewhere in Europe)` → `(somewhere in Canada)`

What it boils down to is whether you purchased your ticket as a whole or whether they are separate ticket.

**Purchased one ticket for Delhi to Calgary**

When checking in at Delhi, you will have your bags tagged to meet you in Calgary. You don't need to re-check the luggage at any intermediate points allowing you to stay airside at all intermediate airports and hence avoid the need for transit visa.

**Journey from Delhi to Calgary is composed of two or more separate tickets**

If this is the case, you will either need to re-check your luggage in Dubai or London. For either of these two intermediate airports, Indian citizens need a visa to go land side so that you can pick up your bags and re-check in.

Comment: Thanks Karan but how do I ascertain whether this is 1 ticket or many as I booked 1 itenerary consisting of multiple airlines as mentioned in my question above

Comment: Where did you purchase the ticket? Was it online? Was it one transaction? Was it through a travel agent?

Comment: It was thru an agent and it has 1 PNR no. He is telling me tht I don't need a transit visa but want to be doubly sure.

Comment: One PNR for the entire ticket is a good omen. When checking in, double check with the agent that your bags are being checked through to Calgary.