# Turkish citizen with Canadian temporary residence: Do I need a transit visa?

Tags: schengen, transit, canada, turkey

I am a student in Canada with a multiple entry visa. Am I able to do the following journey without the need for a transit visa?:

Istanbul - Munich - London - Toronto

The two European airports are:

London - Heathrow (LHR)

Munich - Franz Josef Strauss (MUC)

Please note the layover planned in both Munich and London is short.

Comment: I added the airport names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[London should be fine](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/turkey/transit/no) as you are travelling to Canada with a valid visa. See also [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)

Munich should be fine too. Turkish citizens do need a visa to transit there but there is an exemption for Canadian visa holders, see [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area) for all the details.