# As Philippine do I need a transit visa on a cruise through Schengen countries and the UK and Ireland?

Tags: schengen, uk, transit, cruising, filipino-citizens

I am from Philippines and will do a cruise through Schengen countries and the UK and Ireland in 2015.  I will be doing a sea cruise, coming from Denmark where I will embark, passing through a couple of European countries (hence the Schengen visa) and then also UK and Ireland and again some Schengen countries.

Do I need a UK transit visa in addition to the Schengen visa?

Comment: Please define "cruise". If you actually spend some time for sight-seeing time in the UK, a transit visa won't do.

Comment: Also if you are either departing or arriving in the UK by ship a transit visa won't do. Please give us more of your itinerary. Also I strongly recommend reading the other questions here on UK transit visas, especially this one: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk

Comment: @DJClayworth: Who says a transit visa can't be used when arriving/departing by ship? There's a rule that only air-to-air transits can qualify for the _transit without visa_ scheme, but I can't see anything to the effect that air-to-sea or sea-to-air shouldn't be fine for a transit _with_ a "visitor in transit" visa.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, I was thinking of the Direct Airside Transit Visa. I had forgotten that the Visitor in Transit doesn't require air to air.

Comment: Hi DJClayworth, I will be doing a sea cruise, coming from Denmark where I will embark, passing through a couple of European countries (hence the Schengen visa) and then also UK and Ireland and again some Schengen countries. Is the DATV applicable? or do I not need one?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will need a visa if you get off the boat.

There are different cases though, and the UK government offers [some questionnaire to help you](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa).

## You do not get off the boat

If you do not get off the boat, or to be precise if you do not cross the UK border control, then you do not need a visa, [according to the UK government website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/philippines/transit/no).

## You get off the boat, you stay in UK for less than 48 hours, your destination is not the UK

You a priori need only a [Visitor in Transit Visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/philippines/transit/yes). On the page, it sounds like it is intended for air travel, but the wording lets think you would be eligible for that if you spend less than 48 hours in the UK, you have another destination and do NOT go to Ireland. But keep reading.

## You get off the boat, you stay for more than 48 hours in the UK, or you go to Ireland too

You will need [a visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa) (if you follow the link, see point 3) if you stay for more than 48 hours in the UK or if you are "travelling to the Republic of Ireland, the Channel Islands or the Isle of Man". This is most likely your case.

I encourage you to read the [question @DJClayworth linked](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk) on the topic. The recent changes (Dec. 2014) for Philippines citizens is that you need a transit visa when you transit landside between two flights, so that does not concern you.

I also encourage you to check the travel information page of your cruise, for example [Norwegian cruises offer some very informative page](http://www.ncl.com/about/required-travel-documentation) (not dealing with the UK unfortunately).

Comment: It's worth noting that the cruise operator also has a voice here, In order to reduce its administrative load, the operator may require that _all_ passengers have a UK visa or be otherwise able to enter the UK, even if the passenger doesn't intend to get off the boat.