# UK transit visa, can my brother bring my daughter to UK when travelling to US

Tags: usa, transit, uk, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas

I am already working in UK, my daughter (2 years) is in India and she just got a dependent visa last week. I was supposed to go to India for 2 week to pick her up later this month BUT now there is a possibility that my brother who is in India and may be travelling to US on B2(visit visa) later this month. he does not have any UK visa. So I was wondering on the following points…

1. If he can take US ticket via London (layover flight), can I meet him on Heathrow?
2. Does he needs to have a transit visa?
3. If yes, then where and how long does it take to apply for one?
4. If not, can he bring my daughter outside, so i can take her from arrival point at Heathrow?
5. My daughter needs to go through Immigration control and my brother needs to also take her luggage and bring her to arrival point so i can take her from there. does he also needs to go through immigration control, even through he will not come outside the airport at any point.

On Gov.uk it says that if you have a confirmed flight to your destination within 24 hours and do not go though immigration control then you do not need to have a visa, in my situation he needs to take my daughter to immigration control and to pick her luggage.

Could any one please suggest, what are my options?

Comment: Baggage claim is land side, which means your brother will have to clear immigration. Assuming he is a national of India, he will need a transit visa or entry clearance.  All the bulk of your other questions are at http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk

Comment: yes... but it is confusing.... some forums answers says if its a valid US visa and baggage is already checked in and your stay is less than 24 hours then you can come out with out any transit visa.... this all applies to my brother except that he will go to baggage claim for my daughter and not for himself... so i am just confused...

Comment: Some forums are wrong, like the ones confusing you.  Forums are like that.  As an alternative to reading forums, you might try reading the law.  It's much less contradictory and has a ring of authority to it.  http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2014/2702/made

Comment: "this all applies to my brother except he will go to baggage claim". Then it doesn't apply to him. The issue is not whether he has baggage, it's whether he needs to clear immigration. If he is going to meet you for any reason he will need to clear immigration.

Comment: OK ... https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/yes  this link says that my borther will need visa.. BUT it also says transit without a visa and my brother meets all of the conditions that are mentioned that ... and that is why i am confused

Answer (score 6):

The situation is very simple. Transit passengers in your brother's situation need a visa **if they have to clear immigration**. Your brother has to do that if he is going to meet you. The forums are confusing you because they assume that the only reason to clear immigration is to check bags (which is true 99% of the time).

Comment: +1, concise answer. And to confirm, 'baggage' does not appear anywhere in the corpus of transit visa rules.

Comment: OK ... https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/yes   this link says that my borther will need visa.. BUT it also says transit without a visa and my brother meets all of the conditions that are mentioned that ... and that is why i am confused...

Comment: @patel.milanb It says right at the top of that page: "You should apply for a Visitor in Transit visa if you arrive on a flight and will pass through immigration control before you leave the UK.". Your brother will have to pass through immigration control to deliver your daughter.