# Transit without visa in Gatwick airport

Tags: uk, transit, airports, transit-visas

We are going to come to Gatwick Airport 04.29.2018 at 9.35 pm in the evening to the North Terminal and have next flight in the morning, by EasyJet, 04.30.2018 at 9.05 a.m. to Marocco with all hotel bookings in the hand from the South Terminal. We are planning to have a night in the airport transit zone. Do we need any visas in this case to get from one terminal to another? If some of us have British visas could they take the baggage for the entire group and re-check it? Easy Jet have online ticket. Will it be ok without going outside transit zone?

Comment: Are you saying you have bookings for at hotel at Gatwick Airport? To the best of my knowledge (and google-fu) there is no airside hotel at that airport.

Comment: Please add your nationality.

Comment: Note that since January 2017, Easyjet uses the **North** terminal at Gatwick. If you're basing your plans on information that they fly from South, beware that it may be outdated.

Comment: On the other hand, this means that your assumption that you will arrive in North may also be based on outdated information. Which airline is your arriving flight with?

Answer (score 6):

It does not appear to be possible to transfer airside between terminals at Gatwick. Note that https://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/flying-in/flight-connections/ says:

> If you need to change terminals, you can take our [free shuttle](https://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/passenger-services/Changing-terminals/) 24 hours a day.

The shuttle they refer to is the *landside* peoplemover between the North and South terminals.

So in order to reach your departure terminal, you need to enter the UK. Depending on your nationality, where you're traveling from, and which other visas you hold, you may qualify for the UK's *landside* "Transit Without Visa" scheme, but you have not given enough information in your question to determine that. See [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk) (and links therein) for details.

Comment: You can check what visa you need, if any, at this [earlier answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk). Might be good to edit into the answer.

Comment: As Ukrainian nationals, _if_ you have to go through Border Control, you will need to obtain Visitor in Transit visas in advance. I'm unable to determine if that is necessary at LGW. I see no way to do it if you change terminals. But perhaps your flights are at the same terminal. (If you get the visa, I see no reason you have to sleep at the airport if you are willing to spend the money on a hotel.)