# Connection in gatwick URGENT

Tags: uk, transit, europe, easyjet

Everyone
I need assistance regarding a connection in Gatwick, I have Morrocan passport with polish visa allows me to travel within europe. I have an easyjet flight from Spain connecting in London, I called embassy and airline if I will need visa for this connection and they both agreed that since I don't have check in luggage Iwont have to pass through security.
However on easyjet website and gatwick website, it says that Its mandatory to pass through security.
So do I need a uk visa to do this connection? 
Please advise if u ever had such situation in London Gatwick..
I appreciate your help

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: note that you're asking two different questions here at the same time: whether you need to pass through security or immigration (it's not clear where you see this on the easyJet or Gatwick websites) is not the same thing as whether you need a transit visa.

Comment: @DJClayworth I posted it as a comment on the basis that this question is a duplicate. But actually, the question isn't really about transiting, it's about terminology, so you're right.

Comment: What terminals will your flights use? See this too https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112050/transit-without-visa-in-gatwick-airport

Answer (score 5):

You say that you are arriving in Gatwick from Spain with Easyjet. According to Gatwick Airport's official site (link below) Easyjet passengers transferring flights at Gatwick have to pass through Immigration.

Quote: "Please note that all easyJet passengers must follow option 2, even if you are travelling with hand luggage only."

Option 2 reads: "2. If your hold bags are not through checked, you must collect them at Gatwick. Follow signs to Baggage Reclaim – you will need to pass through Passport Control on your way – and then either use our free GatwickConnects service or proceed to the check-in desk for your next flight."

Source: https://www.gatwickairport.com/at-the-airport/flying-in/flight-connections/