# Transit Visa at Dubai

Tags: visas, transit, dubai, dxb

I am an indian citizen. I will go to Bloemfontein, South Africa for postdoctoral research  at the end of August. I have to stop at Dubai International airport for 4.35 hours for my next connecting flight. I will be travelling through Emirates flight. My question is - Do I need any transit visa at dubai airport for 4.35 stopover time?

Comment: Perhaps we should have a master "Do I need a transit visa for Dubai" question, like [our analogous question for the UK](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk).

Comment: @NateEldredge We usually rely in your linked question to close Dubai duplicates. Don't hesitate to edit it/add your answer if you feel it's incomplete.