# Do I need a transit visa for layover in London

Tags: visas, transit

I am travelling to Austria (Vienna) from India via London(Heathrow). I already have 6 months valid business visa with multiple entries for UK. I will be landed at Terminal 5 and my onboard flight is from Terminal 3 on Heathrow airport. So in this case do I need a transit visa?

Comment: @gmauch this question is about whether someone who *already holds a different UK visa* needs a transit visa when the purpose of the trip is transit rather than the purpose for which the existing visa was issued.  In most jurisdictions, the answer is "no," but after a few minutes of checking the "possible duplicate" question and UK government web pages, I did not see anything that addressed this question for the UK.

Comment: @phoog There is an answer (http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/34107/24596) that links to a UK government site that will tell you if you need a visa to transit through the UK. I think the OP can access this site, answer the questions and know if (s)he needs a transit visa or not.

Comment: @gmauch the site has a "check if you need a UK visa" page, but if you use that page and say that the purpose of your trip is transit, it tells you you need a transit visa, without ever asking whether you already have a visitor visa.  I suspect very strongly, however, that someone with a visitor visa does not need a transit visa, but I cannot find anything to confirm that.

Comment: Akshay: ask at the British Consulate (have you done so already?).

Comment: @phoog, I have an email from the Home Office explaining the policy on your point.  It's not published yet, so an email will have to suffice.  Unfortunately this question is closed.  I may try to edit the canonical question.

Comment: Akshay: Gayot Fow has edited the question that this has been linked to; it appears that your valid multiple-entry visitor visa can be used, as I suspected, for transit.