# With a Tourist visa do I need any other visa to holiday in UK en route from USA to India?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I plan to travel from USA to India with a few days stopover in London. I have an approved UK Tourist visa and a valid I-797 document but my US H-1B visa has expired.

Do I need any other visa (like Transit etc.) in addition to UK Tourist visa in order to holiday in UK before continuing to my home country?

Answer (score 6):

Actually unless you're transiting through UK your US visa plays no role in whether or not you will be allowed in the country.

So if you have a Visitor's visa for the UK you shouldn't have any other visa to enter the country.

Comment: And anyway, you [don't need a transit visa if you have a visitor visa](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/34107/19400).

Comment: Shouldnt have implies that if you have any other visa (say, an American visa) you wont be able to enter :)  I doubt thats the case