# Do I need a transit visa at Heathrow airport while traveling from Toronto to Delhi

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, lhr

I m an Indian citizen, studying in Toronto. Do I need transit visa to fly from Toronto to India via Heathrow airport (London)?

Comment: I AM AN INDIAN CITIZEN AND STUDYING IN TORONTO

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT!

Comment: Indian citizens wont need a transit visa for UK while traveling to and from Canada provided the Canadian visa is a sticker pasted on one of the pages on your passport. If your visa is a piece of paper that you carry along with your passport then you do need a transit visa.

 In case you do have a sticker as a visa even then you cannot have a flight from a different airport or a different terminal that requires you to go through immigration. I am posting this as a comment as this question has been answered elsewhere in complete detail. Please use the search function.

Comment: @ParminderSinghChahal would you please go to http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk and add an answer from your comment.  Just add another answer so as not to lose your input.  Thanks

Comment: Then ping @Relaxed and me so we can up vote your answer

Comment: @GayotFow I have posted my answer at http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/55801/8282    Thanks

Comment: @ParminderSinghChahal, +1 :)