# Transit visa for a 3 hour airside layover in Heathrow airport with Canadian Visitor Visa

Tags: datv

[Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk) - This answer kind of answers my question, but I have a slightly different situation. My work H1-B visa to work in united states has expired and my employer has got my H1-B extension petition approved. I am travelling in a week to India to get stamping of the new H1-B extension on my passport.

My travel originates from San Francisco having a layover of 2 hours in Heathrow airport and I am going to stay airside. **Since I don't have a valid unexpired US visa stamped on my passport, I am wondering if I can assume I am exempt from Direct Airside Transit Visa because I hold a valid stamped visitor visa to Canada valid for another 7 years even though my travel did *not* originate from Canada**

https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa - When I checked if I am exempt from DATV using this link, it clearly mentioned about holding a valid visa to USA, Canada, Australia or NewZealand, **but did not mention that my travel should also originate from one of those countries in order to use the visa issued by that country to be exempt from DATV.**

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Answer (score 1):

There is no such requirement that your travel *originate* in any country. That is why you do not see such a [requirement listed](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no). Merely having the valid visa is sufficient.