# How can I go from Bangalore to Jamaica without transiting via UK or US?

Tags: india, transit-visas, jamaica

I want to travel from Bangalore to Jamaica but I do not have a visa to transit in the US or UK. What is the best way to do this that doesn't require any transit visa?

One option is Bangalore -> Delhi -> Amsterdam -> Panama -> Kingston but there is a 16 hour layover in Panama which I believe requires a transit visa (due to the length of the layover).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)

Comment: Can you confirm your citizenship and any countries you *do* have a visa for.

Comment: Is transit through Canada OK?

Comment: You can do this with just 1 stop and likely on a single ticket going BLR Bangalore - FRA (Frankfurt, Germany) on Lufthansa and FRA - MBJ (Montego Bay, Jamaica) on Condor

Answer (score 4):

By performing a [skyscanner search from Jamaica to "Everywhere" with direct flights only and whole month checked](http://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights-from/jm/cheapest-flights-from-jamaica.html?adults=2&children=0&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=1&preferdirects=true&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&oym=1605&iym=1605), you can get a list of posibilities of where you might transfer.

The list includes several non-uk European countries. Of course, you should watch out for any flights that take place wholly within the Schengen area, as they will require a Schengen visa.

If you can transfer at one airport within the UK, while Indian citizens to need a Direct Airside Transit Visa, I do not think that the requirements for this are very onerous.

Answer (score 1):

You can fly Candor via Germany  - Hamburg to Montego bay

https://www.condor.com/us/get-inspired/condor-worldmap.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I have spent some time trying to find relevant routes for you. Basically, it is really hard to avoid USA and Canada if you want to get to Jamaica. Still, I have found a route through UK with Thomson to reach Montego Bay. You should find flights through Guyana (which has direct connections to Jamaica).