# Indonesian citizen traveling LAX-YYZ-LHR-CAI; do I need transit visas?

Tags: transit, lhr, transit-visas, indonesian-citizens, yyz

I am an Indonesian citizen flying from Los Angeles (LAX), transiting in Canada at Toronto (YYZ), then transiting again in the U.K. at London (LHR), and going to Cairo (CAI), Egypt as my final destination.

Do I need transit visas for Toronto (YYZ) and London (LHR), considering both involve less then 6 hours' layover time? Would I need any other kind of visa?

Comment: See also [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a valid visa for the US, then you are eligible for the
TWOV program for Canada, details of which are [available at this
website](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/twov/travellers.asp):

> Nationals from the following countries qualify for the Transit Without
>   Visa (TWOV) program:
>
> - Indonesia
> - Thailand
> - Taiwan
>
>   - Taiwan passport holders who do not qualify for the visa exemption to visit Canada may still benefit from the TWOV program
> - Philippines
>
> All nationals who qualify for the TWOV program must also meet these
>   conditions:
>
> - They hold a valid passport or travel document issued by the country of which they are a citizen;
> - They hold a valid United States (U.S.) visa;
> - They travel to Canada on an approved airline (either Air Canada, Air Canada Rouge, Air China, WestJet, Cathay Pacific, Philippines
>     Airlines, China Southern, Jazz Air, Sky Regional Airlines Inc., and
>     Air Georgian); and
> - They transit through an approved Canadian airport (either Vancouver International Airport or Toronto’s Pearson International Airport,
>     Terminal 1 only). A change of terminal between flights in Toronto’s
>     Pearson International Airport does not qualify as a condition of the
>     TWOV program.
>
> Notice: Individual travellers cannot apply to the TWOV program; only
>   airports and airlines can submit an application.

For the UK, you [do not need a transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/indonesia/transit/no).