# Which countries can I transit through if I hold a US visitors visa?

Tags: visas, transit, b1-b2-visas

I am going to Grand Cayman but I need to go through London / Dubai and the US. DO I need a separate visa for Dubai and London?

Also, I have a work permit for Grand Cayman Islands.

Per comments by OP: I have an Indian passport with a valid visitor visa. I will travel either through BA or Emirates or American airlines

Comment: Of what country are you a citizen?

Comment: And what airlines are you travelling by?

Comment: @jacoman891 Can't comment on the deleted answer but your source does not prove it wrong as far as I can tell. Care to explain?

Comment: My apologies for being a little over the top. UKBF with not allow you transit on the basis of an ESTA, unless you have physical evidence that it is valid from the airline you are travelling to the US on. Depending on flight configurations, even if your bag is checked all the way through, the US visa clearance etc. may be organised by your airline after immigration. This would be the case, for example, if one was travelling from a smaller airport with a regional carrier. In that case, one would have no evidence of a valid US visa, and there would probably be significant hold-ups.

Comment: @jacoman891 I haven't checked the list recently but if you have an ESTA, you have a citizenship that makes you eligible for visa-free transit in the UK anyway, no? The VWP eligibility list is very restrictive…

Comment: Also, AFAIK, the US does not issue e-visa (I suspect that the language on the gov.uk website implicitly refers to Australian visas) and channels all international flights to specific airports so I have trouble understanding your scenario.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39055/discussion-between-jacoman891-and-relaxed).

Comment: @jacoman891 I have an indian passport with a valid visitor visa. I will travel either through BA or Emirates or American airlines

Comment: The question is too broad: the UK alone has a 10-point list of conditions for US visa holders in-transit. It's better to ask about transit through individual countries.

Comment: @JonathanReez where can one find said list?

Comment: @jacoman891 http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk

Comment: @JonathanReez Exactly where, in this answer or on the official website, do you see a 10-point list of conditions *applying to US visa holders*? And how is it a problem to summarize this list in an answer? It seems to me that you are once again passing judgment without fully understanding the issue. Ironically, you are generally happy closing down questions as duplicate of much more general questions than this one and have been complaining. Would you seriously accept it if the OP would edit many more details in the question?

Comment: @Relaxed read the "One of the following must also apply" section of the UK transit rules. Similar provisions apply in Schengen, Canada, Japan and other airports. Although I guess it's okay if the answer is a simple list of countries with a link to individual transit rules.

Comment: @JonathanReez Funny, that's exactly what I suspected. "**One** of the following must apply" precisely means that the list *is not relevant at all to US visa holders*, they qualify based on the first item, you can stop reading there, period. It's not a list that applies to them, it's a list that might allow people in the opposite situation (no US visa) to qualify anyway. And you are definitely passing judgment without the slightest clue about the topic. Or simply taking the time to read carefully before voting and commenting. That's flirting with trolling and vandalising. Please stop.

Comment: (Incidentally, the answer is not up to date, it's not necessary to be travelling to the US anymore.)

Comment: @Relaxed casting a close vote is not a big deal, we've had this kinds of discussions in Meta for ages. Worst case scenario the close vote fails.

Comment: @JonathanReez On one level, nothing has consequences, it's just a random website. But at this point you are knowingly decreasing the general quality of the contents and creating more work for others for no good reason. You are right that there have been many discussions on meta and you should take them into account. "It does not matter because other people can clean up after me" is not an acceptable reason to vote without even properly reading questions.

Comment: @jacoman891 any discussion of ESTA is irrelevant in this context because the question concerns someone who has a visa.

Comment: @phoog it was not known that the OP was on a normal visa when the issue was raised.

Comment: @jacoman891 the title of the question has said "if I hold a US visitor's visa" fromthe beginning. ESTA is not a visitor's visa.

Comment: @phoog I considered it a possibility at the time. I was wrong to do so, but discusssing it now won't solve anything....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39111/discussion-on-question-by-mansi-which-countries-can-i-transit-through-if-i-hold).

Answer (score 1):

You can transit through the UK on any passport, assuming you have a valid US visa. For more details [see our related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk).

Answer (score 0):

For your itinerary, you need:

1. US visit or transit visa
2. Grand Cayman visa.

You already have all the requirements; as having a US visa exempts you from having a UK transit visa - which you would have required otherwise.

In Dubai - there are no transit visa requirements. If one is required (if your transit is more than 24 hours), it will be arranged for you by the airline along with your accommodation.

Answer (score -1):

As regards the UK: As an Indian passport holder with a US Visitor Visa, you would need to make sure that your flight is booked all the way through on a single booking and your bags are checked through. If checking in for a flight they ask to see your visa for the UK, show them your US visa saying it entitles you to air-side transit in the UK.

This advice also applies to Dubai, although you do not need to show proof of US Visa, only a connecting flight.

Comment: "The deleted answer's advice stands" is not an answer -- it makes the majority of users who _can't see deleted posts_ none the wiser.

Comment: I then go on to repeat the advice. Apoligies if that isn't clear; I'll edit it.

Comment: And is this answer about transiting in London, Dubai, both, or neither?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Edited.