# I'm a Kenyan citizen with an expired US visa, who wishes to fly to Kenya without arranging transit visas. How can I do that?

Tags: air-travel, transit, kenyan-citizens

I am a Kenyan citizen and my US visas expired in December 2015. I was going back home to Kenya through London, and at Boston Logan airport I was refused to be allowed to board the plane as they said I can't transit through London with an expired US visa. I am going back home to Kenya to get them renewed, so what countries can I transit through now that London is out? I need to travel as soon as possible and really don't know what to do.

Comment: You are actually supposed to be able to transit through London with an expired US visa if you're returning from the US. Maybe there is a time limit on the expiration, though.  Direct flights from the US to Kenya are also expected to begin soon.

Comment: You can only transit through the UK if you entered the US on a valid visa less than six months ago. Had this discussion with BA. See here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk

Comment: You can also fly direct from the US to Addis Ababa, where Kenyan citizens do not require a visa.

Answer (score 4):

One option might be to transit through Dubai. From [Visa policy of the United Arab Emirates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_Arab_Emirates):

> Passengers on all international airlines may enter the United Arab Emirates for 96 hours after obtaining a transit visa at the airport. The time difference between the two flights must be over 8 hours and the passenger must continue to a third destination. Passengers also must have a hotel booking. <sup>[1](http://www.emirates247.com/news/emirates/96-hour-transit-visa-for-all-airline-passengers-at-uae-airports-2015-09-20-1.604073)</sup>

There are direct flights from Boston to Dubai, and from Dubai to Nairobi.

Comment: Emirates is what everyone is suggesting, so is it assured that i can take a flight from boston to dubai and then nairobi from there without any issues?

Comment: @miralpatel: We can't guarantee success. However, Dubai has a fairly relaxed transit visa policy. From the information I can find (eg. http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/find_visa_requirements.aspx) it looks like there is either TWOV where you don't leave the airport, or a short term visitor visa which requires a hotel. In your situation I would book through a travel agent and ask them to help confirm your eligibility.

Answer (score 4):

[Turkey also lets people transit through without a previously arranged visa.](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa)

Comment: So something like a turkish airlines should work well right, like from boston to turkey and from there to nairobi?

Comment: I've had friends in your situation do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can transit through the Schengen area without a visa provided you don't need to change airports. There are several possible itineraries which transit through various points in Schengen.

You can also transit through Doha, Qatar (ask BA if they can book this for you because it's on an alliance partner Qatar Airways); Dubai, UAE; Istanbul, Turkey; and almost anywhere else *except* the UK.

Comment: Thank You but i was confused which countries or cities fall in the Schengen, so does it include places like amsterdam and frankfurt?

Comment: @fkraiem sorry, thanks for catching me in my confusion.  Comment deleted.

Comment: SO UAE shouldn't cause any trouble with my expired US visa? @phoog I am a Kenyan Citizen(i have dual citizenship with India) but yeah kenyan passport with expired US visa

Comment: @phoog nvm u just answered it

Comment: @miralpatel Yes, this includes Amsterdam and Frankfurt. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area

Comment: So i have decided to travel with emirates, can anyone confirm on whether or not i can go through dubai without any issues whatsoever.

Comment: @miralpatel See Greg Hewgill's answer.