# UK Transit Visa for a student holding a Spanish NIE card

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas

Could you kindly clarify if the NIE card issued by the Spanish government is equivalent to  a "Common format residence permit issued by EEA member?"

I am an Indian student, studying in Spain.

My layover at London airport is only for 2 hours. Do I require any kind of visa?

Answer (score 1):

The common-format card looks like this (found with an internet search):

[image]

If your card does not look like this, it isn't a common-format residence permit.  However, you may hold another document that exempts you from the transit visa requirement; see [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)