# Question about entering in UK with Spanish national visa

Tags: uk

So I am citizen of Georgia and going with eramus + exchange in Spain. I will have Spanish national visa app for 6 months. My wuestion is do I need additional visa to visit UK?

Comment: Yes. You need a Standard Visitor Visa https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa  See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74136/do-i-need-a-uk-visa-how-and-where-to-apply/74238#74238

Comment: United Kingdom is not a part of schengen.https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/georgia/tourism