# Am I eligible to transit without visa in the UK?

Tags: uk, transit-visas

I am transiting through the UK on my trip from the US to Italy. I am arriving at Heathrow and will be going through immigration to get to Stansted, where I'm catching my flight to Italy. I am a Vietnamese citizen but hold a US visa and last entered the US on such a visa in June. Although my citizenship may require me to apply for a transit visa, I'm wondering if I could do without by meeting the transit without visa concession:

You might be eligible for ‘transit without visa’ if:

- you arrive and depart by air
- have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before - midnight on the day after you arrive
- have the right documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country)
- you’re travelling from (or on part of a reasonable journey from) Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the USA and it’s less than 6 months since you last entered that country with a valid entry visa.

Also worth noting: I am doing a short study course in England this fall for my study abroad program, and I have acquired the appropriate visa for that. Unfortunately the valid date on this visa is the start date of my course, which is after when I wish to transit through the UK to do my Europe trip. I figure re-applying for a visa or applying for a transit visa would be a fuss and am hoping to be able to qualify for the concession. I would appreciate any thoughts and advice.

Comment: Have you checked out the site linked to in the answer [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)? And do you meet the eligibility criteria you quote?