# Transit Visa Requirements

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, kenyan-citizens

Do I need a transit visa through Heathrow to the USA? I hold a Kenyan passport and will be in the USA for four weeks. My transit time at Heathrow is about 2 hours.

Comment: Answered many times - just look at the "Related" questions list on the right.

Answer (score 1):

In short, because you have a valid US visa, **no**, [you do **not** need a UK transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/kenya/transit/somewhere_else/no)

It's all explained [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well