# UK Transit Visa (DATV) needed or not needed?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, layovers, transit-visas, datv

I am based in India.I will be travelling to France & Spain for holidays with my wife on 3rd Apr 2017.
So i have applied for Schengen Visa  and expected to get it by 25th March i.e around 8-9 days prior to my travel dates.

**Main issue:**

We are returning back from Madrid to India on 15th April & my flight from Madrid is having layover in London for 1 hr 50 minutes. After that i have flight from London to Mumbai (British airways)

In such cases while returning back to our country , do we still need UK TRANSIT VISA even for 2 hrs layover at London...
Please guide me.

PS: I do hold Valid US visa & my wife doesnt hold it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In short, because you have a valid US visa, you do **not** need a DATV, while your wife **does** need one.

See [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk) for more details