# I have a valid US greencard, is transit visa necessary

Tags: uk, schengen, transit-visas, russian-citizens, us-residents

I am a Russian citizen with a valiid green card, and I am flying from Miami To Saint Petersburg Russia with 2 layovers in Shengen countries. A 6 hour in London, and 2 hours in Finland. Will I require a transit visa? I will not be leaving the airport, just going to my connecting flight.

Comment: London is not in a Schengen country, lucky for you.

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk . Also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area

Comment: The UK isn't in Schengen so you'll also need to check if you need a UK transit visa.

Answer (score 4):

The premise of your question is incorrect, because the UK is not in the Schengen area.  You will not need a visa to transit in London nor in Finland.