# Is it possible to travel London city when I am in transit for more than 8 hours?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, nepali-citizens, danish-residents

I am traveling to Paris via Ryanair from Copenhagen and there is a 9 hours layover in London, UK. I am planning to go out of the airport for 3 or 4 hours to visit the city during my layover. Do I need to have a transit visa or a general tourist visa, or can I simply go without a visa? I have a residence permit of Denmark. I am from Nepal.

Answer (score 4):

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk) will tell you how to find out if you need a visa.

However, something seems a bit weird here. There aren't any Ryanair London - Paris flights that I know of - according to [their website](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/cheap-flight-destinations) you can only fly from Manchester to Paris (Beauvais). The Copenhagen flights go to London Stansted and London Luton, both quite a long way from Manchester. Are you sure these flights are going through the same airport and there isn't an error somewhere?

Comment: It also seems a very inefficient route. From any of the London airports you could get to Paris by train in much less than 9 hours.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan or you could fly direct from Copenhagen, for that matter :-)