# Transit between LHR and LGW without visa? (Shifting airports inside UK with Irish Biometric visa)

Tags: uk, transit, lhr, ireland, lgw

I am travelling from India(BOM/MAA) to Dublin. I do not have direct flight to DUB as an option, the flight stops at AUH/DXB/LHR and from there to DUB. Apparently, there is a 300£ difference in the flight cost from LHR to DUB and LGW to DUB. Given that I hold an Irish biometric visa, and confirmed tickets to DUB within the same day, am I allowed to go from LHR to LGW without going through the Border Force/immigration checks? In this [link](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/british-irish-visa-scheme/british-irish-visa-scheme) that I found, in section 6 it says that I am allowed to leave on the same day, is it also valid for different airports?

P.S : My visa is employment (single entry) with format D and BC (biometric)

Thanks and Regards, 
Ramana

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)

Comment: Hi Newton, this doesn't talk about the changing of airport case. If not, I will be fine with that itself :-)

Comment: If you follow the links in that answer they will lead you to your answer as well https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa & https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/republic_of_ireland

Comment: It says I need a visa but the three bullet points after that are some conditions which I qualify for and happen to be the exemption from taking a visa. I am not sure if those exemption points are valid for travelling between airports. That's precisely my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two separate questions here, one of which you asked in the text and one of which you asked in the title.

- Can I travel from LHR to LGW to catch another flight without going
  through UK passport control? (The question you asked in the text)

**No**, you cannot travel from LHR to LGW without clearing passport control. Unless an immigration officer were to stay with you for literally the whole trip from LHR to LGW, what would stop you from abandoning your journey to LGW and entering the UK?

- Do I need a separate UK visa to transit/can I transit without a UK
  visa? (The question you asked in the title)

First off, you cannot use the British-Irish visa scheme you linked to. It requires that you first travel to the country that issued the visa, in this case Ireland; and moreover the program applies to short stay and visitor visas, which an employment visa is not.

However, it appears that you may you be eligible nonetheless to transit the UK without a visa -- see [this UK government link here](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/republic_of_ireland). I am not sure if the separate airports will pose an issue; in any case you will still have to clear immigration.

It is also worth noting that if you booked this itinerary on separate tickets (i.e. if you have two separate PNRs and bought the two trips separately; it's not clear to me if this is the case) you may run into some issues. If you did do this, your first airline may deny you boarding in India without a UK visa because from their perspective, your final destination is the UK as they can't "see" your trip to Ireland.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In case I have a flight from LHR to DUB, which I am allowed to travel, will there be a problem with the airline staff while boarding in India?

Comment: @Sentient07: If you have separate tickets, you should really be able to meet UK entry requirements in and of themselves. If your separate LHR-DUB flight is on the same airline as the India-LHR ticket, you *might* get lucky, but strictly speaking the airline will verify that you are eligible to enter the UK, full stop.

Comment: It's separate tickets, and was at LHR itself. I somehow convinced the Emirates people while boarding showing my ticket on Aer Lingus from LHR->DUB. they asked me to write and sign a letter, afterwards, at LHR i informed them about my flight and they verified my visa to Ireland and allowed me to board flight from terminal 2. I didn't face any Hassle. In case anyone is in a similar situation, airside transit wasn't a problem for me, virtue of Irish visa. 
Thanks for those comments and answers!