# Do I need to apply for a UK visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, conferences, common-travel-area

I have to attend a conference in Dublin in July 2018. We will arrive in London on 7th July 2018 (7:30am) and connect to a flight to Dublin at 1:15 pm. After the conference, we will go back to London on 14th July and have a flight from London to Delhi on the 16th July.

Should we apply for a UK visa or Irish visa? Is the type of trip business (academics)? If we apply for a UK visa, should the number of days in UK be 10 or 2?

Comment: I changed your tag from India to Indian-citizens if that's not correct, please change it back

Comment: You can check which Irish visa is appropriate here http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/check-irish-visa Ireland is not in the U.K. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk

Answer (score 1):

Because you're traveling to the UK and the Irish Republic, you can take advantage of the [British Irish Visa Scheme](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/british-irish-visa-scheme/british-irish-visa-scheme), now in place for Indian and Chinese nationals who plan to visit the UK and the Irish Republic.

Comment: The second stay is for 50 hours. As far as my knowledge concern, if I get UK visa under BIVS, then I might not need Irish visa. But I dont know how to apply BIVS? I was following this blog https://travelbooksfood.com/british-irish-visa-scheme-bivs-indians. So according to this I was applying fr UK visa. Then questions were there like how many days you want to stay in UK (I think I should write 10 as 7th to 16th July) and they needed information of our stay. So I should give the address of the two days stay in London. I havent given any details of Ireland. Am I doing right

Comment: @DevismitaSanjay, I think you are. Thanks for giving information about BIVS. I've edited my answer as it appears you can apply once to BIVS to handle your multiple UK entries and entry to Ireland.

Comment: I have been facing many problems while applying for visa. As they are asking who in UK did invite you,what type of business do you have in UK? I was invited by the conference in Dublin. Should I apply for visa taking help from some visa agency

Comment: Since your primary destination is Ireland, apply for an Irish visa with BIVS endorsement. You do not need to apply for a U.K. visa.

Comment: Should I apply for tourist visa or business (academic)?

Comment: @HankyPanky are you sure? Should I apply for Irish visa? My entry and   exit is from London but primary destination in Ireland

Comment: Yes, you are going to Ireland via the UK so UK is your transit point. *I have to attend a conference in Dublin in July 2018* So that is your purpose of travel and that means you apply for a visa to enter Dublin,Ireland. Now fortunately Ireland and UK have a scheme called BIVS which you are eligible for. So on your Irish visa apply for BIVS endorsement and you can go to the UK as well.