# What documents are needed to travel from London to New york?

Tags: usa, air-travel, paperwork, pakistani-citizens

I am a Pakistani citizen. I have a Schengen visa. Can I travel to New York from London or do I require any other document or visa to travel?

Comment: A Schengen visa will not get you into the US. What nationality do you hold?

Comment: Without knowing your citizenship, how could we answer?

Comment: @ZachLipton I am a Pakistani citizen

Comment: Your Schengen visa won't get you into the UK either, so if you're going to London first you'll also need a UK visitor visa for that, as well as a US visa to continue on to the USA.  However, if you're only going to transit in London, and don't have to pass through border control, and you get a US visa, that is sufficient.  See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require a US visitor visa (tourist visa) if you want to travel to New York from London, because a Schengen visa will not get you into the US.

Comment: With just a Schengen visa OP can’t even get to London.

Answer (score 5):

As a Pakistani citizen, you will require a US visitor visa to enter the United States. A Schengen visa is not sufficient.

Comment: Will need a UK visa too unless OP is transiting and that still depends what Schengen visa OP has