# What UK visa does a Pakistani citizen with a US Green Card need?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens, us-residents

I am a US Green Card holder and a Pakistani citizen. I am planning to go Pakistan via the UK, staying for 5-6 days to visit my cousins. Which visa do I need and what is the process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)

Comment: @GregHewgill If he wants to stay 5 or 6 days a transit visa won't do the job.

Comment: Perhaps the OP needs to clarify what is meant by "over there", as I seem to have read it differently from you.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa this is where your answer lies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you want to stay 5 or 6 days in the UK on your way to Pakistan.

You will need a standard visitor visa to spend that long in the UK. [This is the government website explaining how to apply for it.](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply)

Comment: Note that there are [special instructions for applying for a UK visa from the USA](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa).