# Can I still travel if valid visa was in a stolen passport?

Tags: indian-citizens, international-travel, transit-visas

I have planned my trip abroad, leaving in 2 weeks. All my tickets were booked long ago; unfortunately, my passport with the valid visa was stolen.

I am trying to apply for a new passport now. Do I have to get my visa in the new passport? If not, am I allowed to travel out of US without the visa?

My connecting flight is through London. Will I be allowed to board without the visa  in my passport?

I am an Indian citizen, travelling to India: my connection is in London. Can I take the connecting flight in the UK without a US visa in my passport?

Comment: I have not behin my journey yet and i have an indian passport

Comment: What visa(s) did you have in your stolen passport?

Comment: Where are you planning to travel. You don't need a valid USA visa to leave the USA but you will need one to return.

Comment: Is it a US visa and you're asking so that you can transit London without applying for a UK visa?

Comment: My passport with  US stamping is stolen.  I am indian citizen and planned to travel india and my connecting flight is from london. My question is am i allowed to take the connecting flight from London with out visa stamping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)

Comment: Asha: you may require a UK visa, unless you already have one of the other exceptions as [noted in this other question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106). You can [use the tool](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) to see what is needed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no immigration check when you leave the US. So, having a visa or not doesn't prevent you from departing.

However, since you are transiting in the UK, the airline will want to make sure that you are able to transit; and since you don't have a US visa on your new passport, you will need to obtain a UK transit visa if you want to get a boarding pass.

The other option is to transit through another country (by changing the airline you use). For example traveling on Emirates you would not need a transit visa as there are no airside transit requirements for the UAE.

Indian nationals can also transit through the Schengen zone without a visa.

You will need a visa stamped in your new passport or other proof that you are admissible to the US in order to avoid having to obtain a transit visa for the UK.

As you will also need a valid visa in order to board your return flight, you should arrange to have a UK transit visa applied on your passport.

Make sure you bring with you the police report that you filed for your stolen passport to the US embassy in India to obtain another visa stamp, so you can board your return flight and be admitted to the US.