# What can I do: UK transit visa not issued or passport returned: my flight is in two days?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, vfs-global

I applied for a UK direct airside visa at New York VFS on 17th Oct 2018, as I am flying from San Diego to India via London. It is 30 Nov now, and I still didn't get back my passport. My flight is on 5th Dec. I cannot miss the date, as I have booked another connecting flight, as well my appointment in India to stamp the US visa.  What are the options available for me? Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that you need a UK Transit Visa? Assuming you are an Indian national, you would be exempt if you were in the USA on a valid visa. I am indicating the question is a duplicate, and you should look at the original question and check the official UK sites referenced there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)

Comment: @arvind Have you contacted VFS directly about the return of your passport?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus The other question is useful, but it's not a duplicate. Even if the OP doesn't need a UK transit visa, they still need a passport, and that's stuck with the UK authorities.

Comment: If you're unable to get a response from the VFS centre through which you applied, your other option would be to [contact the UKVI help centre](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk/english): it is fee based in England and it available 24 hours a day Monday through Friday (so not from Saturday12 am through Sunday 12 pm **GMT**.) At this point, calling would be faster than email (you pay for that). Also consider getting an emergency certificate from your government; it would not solve the UK transit, you'd have to rebook a direct flight from the US to India.

Answer (score 3):

As written in a comment by @Giorgio:
If you're unable to get a response from the VFS centre through which you applied, your other option would be to [contact the UKVI help centre:](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk/english) it is fee based in England and it available 24 hours a day Monday through Friday (so not from Saturday12 am through Sunday 12 pm GMT.)
At this point, calling would be faster than email (you pay for that). Also consider getting an emergency certificate from your government; it would not solve the UK transit, you'd have to rebook a direct flight from the US to India.

After you have done that, please check that you really need a visa to transfer in the UK, often it is not needed.
[This question deals with that.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)