# Is a sponsorship letter required for obtaining UK transit visa for Indians?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas, schengen-visas

I am travelling to schengen countries next month, and for one of my flights I need a transit visa for the UK, as the flight lays over in London for 10 hours.

So my query is, whether I will need a sponsorship letter attached with visa documents as my wife is travelling with me and in the application form I have shown that I am sponsoring her for the visit.

My confusion is that in the transit visa documents nothing is mentioned about the sponsorship letter.

Comment: Sponsorship letter? That doesn't make sense. You are applying for a transit visa! Of course [you likely don't need a transit visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/34106/3221) anyway.

Comment: You’re going to Schengen countries only but need to transit the UK? Surely there’s a route that would take you via one of the major hubs in Schengen?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.