# Flying from Punta Cana to Cologne via Manchester, will I need a transit visa?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, russian-citizens, manchester

Being a citizen of Russia I am going to fly from Punta Cana to Cologne, Germany with an airside transit in Manchester Airport. I have a Schengen visa, travel only with my hand luggage and there is two hours between the flights. If my connecting flight is through a different terminal, will I need to pass through UK border control? Will I need a UK visa?

Comment: Do both legs of the flight have the same PNR reference, or are you booked with different airlines? What type of Schengen visa do you have? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk

Answer (score 1):

Manchester Airport's website isn't overly helpful in this respect, [but if it's a single ticket then it looks like you can transfer airside](https://www.manchesterairport.co.uk/help/frequently-asked-questions/) and therefore, [wouldn't require a transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/russia/transit/somewhere_else/no)

> If you have booked separately with two airlines (i.e.  there is no transfer agreement in place and you do not have an onward boarding card) then you will need to reclaim your baggage and check in at the relevant terminal. Our three terminals are within walking distance of each other. **If you have a transfer in place, you should follow the signs and proceed on foot to the Flight Transfer centre in the relevant terminal**.

If, however, it's two separate tickets, then you need to pass border control to check in for the onward flight and, thus, may need a transit visa depending on what kind of Schengen visa you hold.

Comment: The OP may be eligible for TWOV depending on what type of Schengen visa he/she holds

Comment: True, I missed that while looking over the requirements, I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: I have Schengen multiple-entry visa “C”. If I have two separate tickets, but don’t have baggage to pick up/to check in will I need UK transit visa?

Comment: @Liubov A ‘D’ Schengen visa is necessary for TWOV. Which airlines are you flying with?

Comment: If it's two separate tickets, presumably the airline of the first flight is going to assume that London is the final destination and thus want OP to provide proof of immigration status, so even if it's hand luggage only, they'd need a visa?