# Visa needed to visit friends in London

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I will be flying to Pittsburgh from Benagluru (India) and want to stop in London for 2-3 days to visit my friend. What sort of visa would I need to go to London? As I am an Indian national I will also hold a student visa for the USA.

Comment: Holding a US student visa makes no difference to UK visitor visa requirements - whether you need one or not is still determined by your citizenship.

Comment: @Traveller it's still reasonable to bring up as it does make a difference in some places and for some types of visas, even in the UK.

Answer (score 5):

To visit friends in the UK you need a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa).

Comment: One could conceivably visit friends during a [Transit Without Visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/34107/31165), for which the OP is eligible via their US student visa.   But that allows for a maximum of 48 hours in the UK, and realistically much less.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert VITV is likely only to apply if they must, due to itinerary, change airports or terminals.  If there is no other reason to leave airside it is highly unlikely that visa-free transit would be granted, particularly given that OP is really intending to use it as a visitor visa.