# Transit visa requirement for UK or Ireland

Tags: uk, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, ireland

I am Indian citizen travelling from Delhi to Toronto. I am having visa for both Canada and USA. My flight is via London and Dublin. Do I need transit visa for UK or Ireland.

Comment: As far as the UK is concerned have you seen this Q&A? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk

Comment: @gparyani I don't think this is a duplicate. That question is about visiting Ireland after a transit in the UK, whereas this one is about transiting in both Ireland and the UK.

Answer (score 0):

Since the UK and Ireland have a Common Travel Area, any flight from London to Dublin will be inside the Common Travel Area. As a result, you will need a regular UK tourist visa. A transit visa won't be enough. You have to pass regular border control for entering the UK in order to get to the flight from London to Dublin.