# entering London during my transit i am from Saudi Arabia

Tags: visas, usa, transit, london, saudi-arabia

My wife and I have flight from Saudi to Geneva round trip by BA. On my flight back I have a layover for about 10 hours in London. I would like to visit London and I do not have UK visa. I have a USA visa but wife does not have one. Is it possible for both of us to enter London?

Answer (score 1):

You can check what kind of visa you need to transit in the UK [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk). However the short answer is that both of you need a visa to transit in the UK.

You can apply for either an Airside visa, in which case you cannot leave the airport, or a Landside visa which will allow you to pass through immigration and visit London

Comment: The Visitor in Transit visa, and transit without visa on arrival, are intended for transit, not sightseeing, and they have refused people entry for trying to use them for tourism. They really need a Standard Visitor visa for this.

Comment: "Intended for transit" doesn't mean you can't do some visiting while you are waiting. As long as transit is your main purpose and you are making the shortest reasonable transit time you could you should be fine.

Comment: Right, but that's not really transit if they don't actually need to clear immigration to transit.