# Had a question about transit visa for UK

Tags: visas, usa, transit, india, transit-visas

I’m traveling from India to USA in which i got a 15 hour layover at London airport. My flight will land at London at 6 p.m. and other flight will take off at 9 a.m. next day. So an overnight stay. So will I be needing a transit visa? I don't want to get out of the airport.

Comment: Pehrpas this Q&A will help you https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk

Comment: Note that there is no such place as "London Airport". Most long-haul flights go via Heathrow or Gatwick.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Heathrow airport, I meant.