# First Entry Member State Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, poland

I'm appying for a Schengen visa to go to Poland. I bought a flight with a stop in London UK, so it's not a selectable country in the online form as a "First Entry Member State". Will I have problems with this question? What should I put there? Thanks

PS i only need the passport to get through the UK.

Comment: Can I get my visa declined for this though?

Comment: Unlikely - Schengen authorities won’t care where you’re entering from, they will only care about how you intend to leave the Schengen area

Comment: I will be leaving through UK again

Comment: "Can I get my visa declined for this though?" Why would it be grounds for a visa refusal? Say you're flying from Tokyo. You could fly direct to Brussels or with a change in Moscow, in Frankfurt, or in London.  Why would they care whether you're planning to fly by way of any particular airport?

Comment: Thank you guys, its just its my first time traveling abroad and i found this cheap flight to Poland with one stop in Heathrow (London) then I was doing the online form and i noticed that UK wasn't there, i thought there were all EU countries and i got a bit paranoid because i already book the flight

Answer (score 8):

The UK is not part of the Schengen area, so you cannot enter the Schengen area there.  Assuming you're flying from somewhere outside Europe to the UK and then Poland, you should put *Poland* in response to that question.

Comment: Another consequence of the UK not being a part of Schengen, is that a Schengen visa doesn't allow you to enter the UK, maybe it would be a good idea to read https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk

Comment: @Henrik this is true, but the asker of the question seems to have taken it into account.

Comment: I misssed that PS, but then it's probably good to have if others find the question.

Comment: I checked the page "https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa" and i got "You do not need a visa to come to the UK"  with the following answers "What are you coming to the UK to do?" >Transit (on your way to somewhere else) "Where are you travelling to?" >Somewhere else

Comment: You're right, i went to the Polish embassy today and the guy told me that there are no problems with it. Thank you guys for your support

Answer (score 2):

**phoog** is absolutely correct. It is POLAND.

When the term *Member State* is used by the European Union it usually refers to any of 28 countries forming the EU. However, as the Schengen borders and visa codes do not apply to six of these states (by opt-out or by not being ready yet) and four non-EU states participate by special agreements, in this case the term refers to any of the 26 states in the Schengen Area, the so-called Schengen States. Yes, it is bad wording.