# Travelling through UK, what is considered a "common format residence permit"?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, france, transit-visas

I will be travelling through UK (Manchester) from Africa to Paris.

I will pass through border controls since I have to pick up my luggage and check in again in a different terminal but still at Manchester Airport. It is a landside transit.

My flight to Paris is on the same day (7 hours later).
I have a Lebanese passport and a 10-year French residence permit (titre de séjour). 
It was issued in April 2010 (to April 2020). 
It is plastified, pink/purple in color, and has a bull and 5 stars on it. It does not have a chip.  It is a little bit bigger than the "credit-card sized model" (mine is 10.5 cm by 7.5 cm).

Having a common format EEA residence permit allows me to transit via the UK.

Is the residence permit that I have considered a common format residence permit? Even without a chip and not the credit card size?

Comment: As a matter of principle, I don’t think questions should be marked as duplicates of a question that is itself marked as a duplicate. Therefore I’m voting to reopen.

Comment: @MJeffyes the solution to that problem is to mark the other question as another duplicate of this question's duplicate, not to reopen this question.

Comment: @phoog Yes, but [the question that that question was marked as a duplicate of](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk) didn't actually answer this question.

Comment: did you manage?

Answer (score 3):

The common format residence permit is indeed a red and blue (or pink and purple, depending on the ambient lighting) card with a bull and stars. Older ones will not have a chip, but they remain valid even without a chip. France added the chip to theirs in June 2011.

France residence permits after and before June 2011:
[image: France residence permits after and before 2011]
Image source: [Government of France](http://www.val-de-marne.gouv.fr/Demarches-administratives/Etrangers/L-Hay-les-Roses/Renouvellement-de-titre-de-sejour)

You will need to show both your passport and this residence permit when you check in for your flight in Africa, so that the airline can confirm your ability to transit the UK. They will deny boarding without it.

Comment: @Mathfrance If the only difference is that you do not have a chip, you are still OK. The airline reads the machine readable lines on the back, and doesn't need to read the chip.

Answer (score 0):

A [new uniform format (or common format)](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32017R1954) had been adopted by the EU in 2017  and issued since 2019. Its use has been mandatory for member states (incl. EEA and Switzerland) since 2021. Existing cards will remain valid until their expiry dates or by 3 August 2026 (whichever is the earliest).

[image]