# I am an Indian National holding a German residence permit. Do I need a UK Transit Visa?

Tags: uk, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, german-residents

We are currently residing in Germany and are traveling to India on 10th October and our itinerary has a transit in London. We are not sure if we need a transit visa. I have a couple of questions in this regard:

1. We do have a *German residence permit* and are confused if that is what they call a *common format residence permit*.
2. If yes, the validity on our residence permit had expired few months back and we were issued a ***Fiktionsbescheinigung***. Does this allow us to still fall under the exemption of carrying *"a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland"*?.
3. Also, effective from 1st October ***"you will not be able to use an EU, EEA or Swiss national ID card to enter the UK"***. Does this affect us in anyway?

Comment: Q3 = from 1 Oct you’ll need a passport to enter the UK (assuming your transit is not airside).

Comment: You note that the "validity of your residence permit **had** expired. If its term expired, the permit is apt to be seen as valueless. Thus, the real question here is whether your **Fiktionsbescheinigung** is a "Common Format Resident Permit issued by an EEA country." Please attach an image of that document into your question (using the "edit" button below the question text), having first obscured personal info (name, address, card number, etc.) so your personal details are not revealed.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143203/travelling-through-uk-what-is-considered-a-common-format-residence-permit