# I am an Indian passport holder with a Type 1 Dutch residence permit transiting through London. I wanted to clarify if needed a transit Visa or not?

Tags: uk, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, netherlands

I have seen multiple people ask a similar question but it was asked a few years ago and I wanted to clarify if the rules were still the same. I have a temporary residence permit(a plastic card) for the Netherlands (Type 1, Regulier Bepaalde Tijd). I'm taking a British Airways flight from Amsterdam to Chennai with a transit in London. My flight arrives and departs on the same day. I wanted to know if my residence permit counts as the "common format residence permit" listed as an exemption on the UK government website. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Related question [What is considered a common format residence permit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143203/travelling-through-uk-what-is-considered-a-common-format-residence-permit)