# Enter UK with an expired H1B Visa

Tags: uk, transit, indian-citizens, h1b-visas, us-residents

I am an Indian citizen residing in the USA. I have an expired H1B visa with an approved I-797 until 2021.

I am planning to travel from USA to India with a stopover in London (intend to get my H1B stamped while in India). I have an approved 6-month UK Visitor Visa.

Would i face any problems boarding the flight from USA to London given that I have an expired H1B?

Comment: Your UK Visitor visa also allows you to transit.  Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)

Answer (score 1):

No. The airline won't care about US visas at that point, they'll want to see a valid UK visa. On the way BACK to the US you'll need to show the new H1B