# Bombay to San Francisco via Amsterdam and London

Tags: uk, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, schengen-visas

My flight is from BOM to SFO and have 2 layovers first 1 hour 10mins in Amsterdam (Schengen State) and second at London Heathrow (Non Schengen State).

My question is will I need any transit visa for either Amsterdam or London?

I have a valid US visa and my final destination is a US city.

I was able to find questions where both the layovers were Schengen States but not for a Schengen state and a non Schengen State.

P.s. I’m an Indian National

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk) and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that question doesn’t really solve my query. I already checked that link from gov.uk and based on that it says I wouldn’t need a transit visa there. But my concern is about the layover at Amsterdam, will I need a transit visa there? is the flight from Amsterdam to London accessible from the International transit area? The airline is giving very vague replies

Comment: Doesn’t item 5 of the second linked question answer your query? Are all legs of the journey booked on one ticket? Will you need to reclaim baggage in Amsterdam?

Comment: Since you haven't supplied any flight information about landing and leaving in Amsterdam,  how do you expect us to give an answer to that part of the question? Look up the gates and then look at the Airport map, where the Passport / Customs area is clearly shown.

Comment: Did you check both links? In the answers in the second link you will find information for your Amsterdam layover.