# London airport transit visa

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, transit-visas

I have flying from France to Qatar tomorrow, I have to go from France to London Airport from Terminal 4 to Terminal5, do I have a teransivisa to enter London Airport?

Comment: What's you nationality?

Comment: Standard answer: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk