# Transit UK visa required or not

Tags: canada, transit-visas, lhr, connecting-flights, mumbai

I have a Canadian Tourist Visa and planning to leave from Mumbai to Vancouver on British Airways Flight in August 2023.
There is a halt of 10 hours at Heathrow
I will be landing at Terminal 3 and connecting flight to Vancouver will leave from Terminal 5.
In such situation:

1. Do I need to pass through border control to get a bus or train or taxi to reach terminal 5
2. Do I need a transit visa at Heathrow and if so how do I get it?
3. As my flights are all British Airways, can I book check in baggage from Mumbai to Vancouver for easy passage at Heathrow

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179319/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-uk-to-change-terminals-at-lhr will help with (2) - it depends on your nationality

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket/booking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)

Answer (score 1):

If you’ve booked this as a connecting journey (one Passenger Name Record) you should be able to check your baggage through to Vancouver and your flight itinerary should not typically involve transferring baggage, check-in or passport control. Transferring between terminals is explained on the Heathrow website https://www.heathrow.com/connecting-flights

This UK government website will tell you if you need a transit visa, and if so, how to apply. As a Canadian visa holder travelling to Canada it’s likely that you don’t need one [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)