# Schengen to Schengen with connecting flight via UK (non-Schengen)

Tags: uk, air-travel, schengen, indian-citizens, iceland

Indian here with a single-entry Schengen tourist visa. I'm planning to visit Iceland (first port of entry) then Europe with a connecting flight via the UK (non-Schengen). Can I travel between Iceland and Europe with a connecting flight in the UK and still roam around Europe or will I be stamped out and not allowed into Europe?

Comment: Are you transiting via the UK with a single ticket?  Which airport?

Comment: If that is your plan, you should say so in the visa application and get a double/multiple entry visa. Unless you already have the visa and now plan to add some sightseeing.

Comment: @lambshaanxy while it's always better when questioners provide more info, in this case I don't think there's any answer to your questions that could change the answer.

Comment: @lambshaanxy even if on a single ticket, OP will be stamped out when they leave Iceland and shouldn’t be allowed back in Schengen.

Comment: @lambshaanxy and others thanks so I need to take direct fight from iceland to Europe or get at least double entry schengen visa

Comment: Just FTR.  The mention of a "double/multiple entry visa" is very confusing and misguiding to the OP or anyone else reading in the future.  Obscure theoretical abstractions are not "possibilities".

Comment: @Fattie how is it confusing? Schengen multiple entry visas are a thing

Comment: in the op's situation it would be like saying "or, quickly marry a diplomat and get a diplomatic passport".  very hard to get

Comment: @Fattie if the visa hasn't been issued (it's not clear from the question) then there's no reason to think that a double or multiple entry visa is difficult to get.  Someone who qualifies for a single entry visa for an itinerary not involving the UK is going to qualify for a double or multiple entry visa for an itinerary that does involve the UK.

Comment: You need to ask the embassies of all the jurisdictions involved, and your travel agent and your airline.

The most obvious answer should be that none of that Schengen or any other visa details should come into this, unless you left the 'airside' at the stop-over airport.

So long as you don't set foot 'ground-side' you have not officially entered the local jurisdiction and so are still officially aboard the aircraft.

Comment: Thanks all I have decided to ditch the stupid UK and go through Copenhagen instead...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Do not do this.

If you travel Schengen to Schengen via Non-Schengen what will happen is the following:

- You will get a Schengen exit stamp in Iceland, as you are exiting the Schengen Area.
- You will thus have used up your single entry, and can not reenter.
- As a result, in the UK you will be refused boarding for your next flight, and will be put on the next flight to India.

A few Indian collegues of mine had exactly that happen to them. They were spending two weeks in Sweden on business, and decided they wanted to take advantage of the weekend to see Prague (indeed, why not?). But they booked a flight via Kyiv, as that was cheapest, and ended up back in India earlier than expected...

Comment: Wouldn’t the OP need a [UK transit visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk) to be allowed to board the flight *to* the UK?

Comment: @lambshaanxy The current TWOV rules only refer to ‘D’ visas/residence permits, and a Schengen Approved Destination Scheme (ADS) group tourism visa; unless I’m missing something a ‘C’ visa isn’t listed within the exemptions https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no

Comment: Thanks all, so I need to take direct fight from iceland to Europe or get at least double entry schengen visa...correct?

Comment: @Traveller will I also need a UK transit visa? I doubt since just as non-schengen to non-schengen connection in a schengen country is possible without schengen transit visa, schengen to schengen in a non-schengen should be allowed too...

Comment: @RadiumBall "just as non-schengen to non-schengen connection in a schengen country is possible without schengen transit visa, schengen to schengen in a non-schengen should be allowed too": Some people _do_ need transit visas in the Schengen area when changing from a non-Schengen arrival to a non-Schengen departure, including Indian citizens in certain Schengen countries.  Similarly, the UK also requires some people in transit to have a transit visa even if they do not intend to clear passport controls.

Comment: @RadiumBall Unless you fulfil one of the TWOV exemptions (which as far as I can tell you do not), you *will need a visa* to transit the UK, whether that’s airside or not. A Schengen ‘C’ visa doesn’t allow Indian citizens to transit the UK.

Comment: I think in the link you provided clearly states this as an Exemptions "a flight ticket from the Schengen area, if you can prove that you entered the Schengen area in the previous 30 days on the basis of a valid Schengen ADS visa" and I satisfy this exemption...further dropped a mail to airline....let's see what they have to say...anyway what happens if you don't have a transit visa...I am anyway getting of the UK...so what??

Comment: @RadiumBall - you must take a direct flight. end of story.  ("multiple entry visa" idea is fantastical)

Comment: @RadiumBall I doubt that your Schengen visa is a "Schengen ADS visa."  ADS stands for "approved destination status," which is a program facilitating Chinese group tourism to member states.  Your question implies that you are not traveling as part of a Chinese tour group.

Comment: @RadiumBall "what happens if ..." **Krist has written it in black and white** ".. will be put on the next flight to India" as happened to his colleagues. (I lived in India for some years **and indeed, exactly this has also happened** to Indian colleagues I know!)  Take care about "emailing the airline", you're dealing with a min. wage employee who knows nothing and is googling timatic results. you *can not* go through the UK, it's very simple. It's surprising your colleagu4es haven't pointed this out as it's a very basic 'gotchya" known to all Indianms who do biz.